# awk variable cannot concatenate the letter "z" returned by substr() inside for loop

Tags: awk

While creating a encryption character set for each of the letter using a key, the letter `z` is not seeming to be added to the variable. What is wrong with the code? Please point out.

I have tried adding extra characters after `z` and increasing the counter in for loop, but `z` is not being concatenated to the string.

```
BEGIN {
    charset="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    printf("Enter your choice:\n1. Encryption.\n2. Decryption.\n")
    getline choice < "-"
    print "Enter Key:"
    getline key < "-"
    for(i=1;i<=62;i++) {
            newch = substr(charset,(i+key)%62,1)
            encharset = encharset newch
            print encharset
    }
}
```

Output

```
Enter your choice:
1. Encryption.
2. Decryption.
1
Enter Key:
19
J
JK
JKL
JKLM
JKLMN
JKLMNO
JKLMNOP
JKLMNOPQ
JKLMNOPQR
JKLMNOPQRS
JKLMNOPQRST
JKLMNOPQRSTU
JKLMNOPQRSTUV
JKLMNOPQRSTUVW
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZa
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZab
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabc
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcd
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcde
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdef
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefg
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefgh
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghi
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghij
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijk
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkl
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklm
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmn
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmno
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnop
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopq
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqr
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrs
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrst
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstu
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy   #from this line "z" is not appearing in the string
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy01
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy012
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy01234
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy012345
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy01234567
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy012345678
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789A
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789AB
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789ABC
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789ABCD
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789ABCDE
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789ABCDEF
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789ABCDEFG
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789ABCDEFGH
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789ABCDEFGHI
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy0123456789ABCDEFGHI
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the modulo operator quite correctly.

```
echo 0 62  | awk '{ print $1 % $2 }'     # "0"
echo 1 62  | awk '{ print $1 % $2 }'     # "1"
echo 61 62 | awk '{ print $1 % $2 }'     # "61"
echo 62 62 | awk '{ print $1 % $2 }'     # "0" not "62"
```

Your `z` is the 62nd character of the `charset` string. You're calculating offsets modulo 62, which means your resultant values can be in the range `0`..`61`. Since `awk` expects string offsets from `1`, what you need to do is to add `1` to your resultant value to calculate the offset so that it's in the range `1`..`62`:

```
newch = substr(charset, ( (i+key)%62 )+1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works.

Comment: You also need to change the loop, to count as if zero indexed: `for(i=0;i<62;i++)`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor not that I can see - the `i` is used as an offset to the `key` to index `1..62`. The output of the original function was `0..61`, where outputs `0` and `1` would have both indexed the first character of `charset`; mine is `1..62`.

Answer (score 3):

The `substr()` function picks out a substring from a string.  The position given as the second argument is counted from 1, not 0, while the modulus operator, when used as `%62`, would give you integers between 0 and 61.

This means that you will have to modify your call to `substr()` into

```
newch = substr(charset, 1 + ((i + key)%62), 1)
```

Alternatively, to avoid magic constants,

```
newch = substr(charset, 1 + ((i + key)%length(charset)), 1)
```

Comment: You also need to change the loop, to count as if zero indexed: `for(i=0;i<62;i++)`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, possibly, depending on what the intention is with that loop. The `i` is never used to index into the string directly.